# unsupported operand type trying to use image as array

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, typeerror

```
def SaveImg(img, path, data):
    #image, temp = Image.fromarray((img-bg+127).astype(np.uint8)), data['temps']

img=img.astype(np.uint8)
#y=127
#x=y.astype(np.uint8)
image, temp = Image.fromarray(img-bg), data['temps']
outFile=path+"/%s - %f-%f C.png" % (datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H.%M.%S"), temp[0], temp[1])
image.save(outFile)
print "Saving to", outFile
#time.sleep(5)
```

This is my function to save images from a camera linked to my computer.
The error I get is:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

I can't understand where the problem is. Also, I'm changing a code that I did't write and the first line of the function should be the right one but it gives me the same error.

I tried to make some print to see what is wrong but I can't see anything that is `NoneType`; when I print I don't get `NoneType` or all zeros arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I see a problem in this line of code:

image, temp = Image.fromarray(**img-bg**), data['temps']

`bg` is apparently `None`. You can't subtract `None` from something, hence the 'unsupported operand type' error.

From the code you showed it's impossible to deduce what `bg` should be, or where it is initialized or calculated. From the name I suspect it's a view of the camera without anything in it (i.e., the 'background'). Subtracting a background picture from another picture makes sense, but fails if there is no background picture... Is there a way to view the rest of the code? Is this from some open-source project?

Comment: In the line `self.bg=self.cm.imgInterface.snap()` the background picture is acquired. Can you verify that `self.bg` actually contains a valid image at that time? Also I can nowhere in the code you provided find the operation `img-bg` as you show in your code snippet, so I can't see how your code fits in the larger whole. It could be, for example, that you should use `img - self.bg`, but that's a wild guess. Can you post your entire code somewhere?

Comment: I see you use backslashes (\\) in strings. You either have to escape them, or use 'raw' strings. So, either `'D:\\pavo-th\\pictures'` or `r'D:\pavo-th\pictures'`, or even better, use `os.path.join` to compose filenames with directorynames in them. I'm not sure if this is the only problem, but it is significant.